# Haml/Sass Syntax Highlighting in Notepad++?

Tags: ruby, notepad++, haml, sass

Has anybody made this yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find one here 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haml/o9Z_CoAEdOA/discussion

You'll find the userDefineLang.xml at the bottom. Just click Download and add it to your Notepad++ AppData dir. (%APPDATA%/Notepad++).

Hope it helps.

*PS:
Sass is great!*

Comment: Sweet, that solves my sass problem. Thank you. Now if only I could find one for haml..

Comment: @Zach L: check this https://groups.google.com/d/topic/haml/o9Z_CoAEdOA/discussion

Comment: Wouldn't open for me.  With Peazip it asked for a password, and 7zip just plain gave me an error.  Any chance you could upload it again somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a highlighting XML-file [here](http://tech.wiedo.nl/sass-3-notepad-user-defined-syntax-highlighti)

For more information on highlighting and auto-compiling of sass-files: [link](https://deekaysblog.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/notepad-series-3-sass-highlighting-and-auto-compile/)

Answer (score 1):

Made one, too. Based on Wouter Beugelsdijk's template - but with [dark theme](https://bitbucket.org/mariuszz/notepad-sass-highlighting-dark/) :)

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently not](http://groups-beta.google.com/group/haml/web/syntax-highlighting).

Comment: True, I saw this web page while searching for Haml syntax for Notepad++. But I was wondering if anybody has taken the time to make a 'User Defined Language' for Haml in Notepad++ without uploading it anywhere..

Comment: Check this link:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haml/o9Z_CoAEdOA/discussion